# Need to add partition on screen with scrollbar and checkbox

Tags: html, css, user-interface

[image: Reference image]

I am designing a page that consists of 5 fields and different partitions with a scrollbar.

Requirement:

- The page should have 5 non-editable fields.
- Below these 5 fields 3 partitions(left, center, and right) need to be included with the scrollbar.

Problem:

- How to add a partition on the left side of the page that holds different contexts with a checkbox and a scrollbar to it.

For e.g

The left side partition will have lets say 5 different values

- India (followed by checkbox)
- Australia (followed by checkbox)
- Singapore (Followed by checkbox)
  likewise, and user should click on the checkbox and if the lists are big then it should have a scrollbar

Sample code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Non-Editable Form</title>
    <style>
        form {
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: max-content 1fr;
            gap: 10px;
            max-width: 300px; /* Adjust the width as needed */
            justify-content: flex-start; /* Align to the left */
        }

        label {
            margin-bottom: 10px; /* Add margin between label-value pairs */
        }

        div {
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
        }

        input {
            margin-left: 10px; /* Add margin between label and input */
            margin-bottom: 10px; /* Add margin between text boxes */
        }

        .double-column {
            grid-column: span 2;
        }

        /* Add styles for the container with a scrollbar */
        .scroll-container {
            max-height: 200px; /* Set the maximum height as needed */
            overflow: auto;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            padding: 10px;
            margin-top: 10px; /* Add margin at the top of the scrollable container */
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <form>
        <div>
            <label for="field1">Field 1:</label>
            <input type="text" id="field1" value="Non-Editable Value 1" readonly>
        </div>

        <div class="double-column">
            <label for="field2">Field 2:</label>
            <input type="text" id="field2" value="Non-Editable Value 2" readonly>
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="field3">Field 3:</label>
            <input type="text" id="field3" value="Non-Editable Value 3" readonly>
        </div>

        <div class="double-column">
            <label for="field4">Field 4:</label>
            <input type="text" id="field4" value="Non-Editable Value 4" readonly>
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="field5">Field 5:</label>
            <input type="text" id="field5" value="Non-Editable Value 5" readonly>
        </div>

        <!-- Add any other form elements or buttons as needed -->

    </form>

    <!-- Container with scrollbar -->
    <div class="scroll-container">
        <!-- Add more content to demonstrate the scrollbar -->
        <p>India</p>
        <p>Australia</p>
        <p>More content...</p>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is a partition? A column maybe? It might be easier if you create an image in https://www.photopea.com/ or something similar, as the wording of your question is unclear. I'm sure an image would explain more than words would

Comment: @Bjorn.B Thanks for responding. I have uploaded one image for reference. Hope that will help

Comment: What have you tried? The 5 non-editable elements at the top appear to be irrelevant to the question, but there doesn't seem to be anything else in the code given. Please show us what attempt you have made.

Comment: @AHaworth Apologies for not adding the code. I have added the container assuming the scrollbar to appear. But it's coming as a box on UI with this code.  I have added the sample code in the original question.

Comment: Your `.scroll-container` is a flex container, so you should probably start by adding `flex-direction: column;`, if you want India, Australia, ... to go _below_ each other, instead of _next_ to each other.